# The are errors arising in iOS apps with move to iOS 10 from earlier (8 or 9) iOS versions

Tags: ios, xcode

It is a big sudden problem that came with iOS 10. There are several errors I and others report:

> < *on new project:* >
>
> 1. The maximum number of apps for free development profiles has been reached.
>
> <  *on the project working on macOS before 10 (8 or 9):*  >
>
> 1. mycode0001 requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the
>    project editor.
> 2. Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.0'

It is critical for quite a few developers to know how to address this!

Comment: Anecdotally, Apple seems now to permit only five free-certificate-signed apps, either per device or in total per week depending on whom you source your information from. How many are you trying to use?

Comment: @Tommy Good point, I have >50 signed with 'developer' lic.

Comment: @Tommy This issue had been reiterated on StackExchang (in case you don't notice), but I didn't see if there was anything useful there.

Comment: @Tommy After all 'device management' has disappeared from 'General' upon recommended fixes

Answer (score 0):

> I followed upon @Tommy suggestions by cutting more than fifty Apps licensed for 'developer'.
>
> I as well watched WWDC16 presentation "What's New in Xcode App Signing".
>
> These did address my issues 100% so far.